# RCT_EXPORT_METHOD for Zendesk support SDK

Tags: javascript, objective-c, react-native

I'm trying to bridge the Zendesk Support SDK to render in my react native app.

Here is what I would normally do in objective-c:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <ZendeskSDK/ZendeskSDK.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (IBAction)ButtonPress:(id)sender {
    [ZDKHelpCenter presentHelpCenterWithViewController:self];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

How can I use RCT_EXPORT_METHOD to bridge?

At the moment I got something like this:

```
#import "zendeskSupportView.h"
#import <ZendeskSDK/ZendeskSDK.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>
#import <React/UIView+React.h>

@implementation zendeskSupportView

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(findEvents:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
  UIViewController *rootController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
  rootController = [rootController topMostController];
  [ZDKHelpCenter presentHelpCenterWithViewController:rootController];

}



@end
```

Comment: Did you read documentation? Download their sample app and watch video here https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/ios/welcome

Comment: Yes, I did, implemented for objective-c, no issue there. I'm asking to implement it with React native

Comment: @Hyacinthe Do you want to trigger [ZDKHelpCenter presentHelpCenterWithViewController:self]; from js side like when a button is pressed in react component?

Comment: Hi @while1, yes exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting native module you can refer to react native [module documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) or have a look at a [gist of a small module](https://gist.github.com/gShrey/d711b7a3e2bca6f7f72d0345623f2fbe) i created in my project earlier which opens IOS settings app.

In your RCT_EXPORT_METHOD macro code, you will need to call `[ZDKHelpCenter presentHelpCenterWithViewController:self];` . As there is no controller instance available directly in this function, you can do something like this:

```
UIViewController *rootController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
rootController = [rootController topMostController];
[ZDKHelpCenter presentHelpCenterWithViewController:rootController];
```

Above code, passes topmost controller in ios controllers stack to ZendDeskHelpCenter.

Comment: thanks for the answer mate. Where do you define topMostController?

Comment: What problem are you getting in the code above? Your problem seems to little bit open ended. If yours is open source project, i will be happy to look at code directly.

Comment: Can you reach me on skype for like 5 min? my id is hamon.hyacinthe